# FREETEXT Search in SQL Server 2012 with Ordering by Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to use the `FREETEXT` in the where clause of SQL Server 2012 and yet be able to order the results by their relevancy to search terms.

I know I can use `FREETEXTTABLE`, however the SQL statement will be more of a `JOIN` rather than being in the `WHERE` clause. This is important to me since I need to combine the `FREETEXT` statement with other logical comparisons.

Desired state is to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT Title 
FROM Document 
WHERE FREETEXT(Contents, Title, 'Approved Draft') OR (Status = 'Approved Draft')
ORDER BY RANK? DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `FREETEXTTABLE` in order to get the Rank. You'll still be able to combine this with other logical comparisons though.

Here's an example of how you can modify your query. Keep in mind that your logic will result in a 0 rank when `Document.Status = 'Approved Draft'` so you'll need to decide what you want to do in that case.

```
SELECT Document.Title, qFreeText.RANK
FROM Document
LEFT JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Contents, Title, 'Approved Draft') AS qFreeText
   ON Document.ID = qFreeText.KEY
WHERE (Document.Status = 'Approved Draft') OR (qFreeText.KEY IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY qFreeText.RANK DESC
```